# Split values into separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

```
WITH Numbers AS (SELECT Table.ProductNumber FROM Table WITH (NOLOCK))
```

returns ProductNumber like `1`, `2`, `3,4,5` - some are comma separated, so I want to split and than do proper `SELECT` on them with `WHERE`

What I got so far is:

```
SELECT @XML = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(Numbers , ',' ,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')
SELECT [ProductNumber ] = T.c.value('.','varchar(60)') FROM @XML.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
```

But I dont know how to convert selected SQL resource `Numbers` into string for XML conversion and not loose track of which `ProductNumber` were in which row

Comment: So your each and every row stored ProductNumber as in comma separated format?

Comment: Not every one. Just some of them

Comment: Do you have any other column in this Table?

Comment: Yes, every have unique ID and I want so select ID with a `ProductNumber` = 'something' which can be in comma separated row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query is you are `assigning` the converted `xml` to a `variable`, but here only the last row will be stored in that `variable`.

Try something like this.

```
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') splt_num
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>'
                     + Replace(ProductNumber, ',', '</M><M>')
                     + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   yourtable) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```