# Costful XML sql operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

This query works, but it's cost is very big, how to get same result but with less cost?

```
SELECT ProductID, Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(60)') ProductNumber FROM (
    SELECT ProductID, Cast ('<M>' + Replace(ProductNumber, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data FROM Table
) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: You should describe the problem that led to this solution.

Comment: @AlexK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737104/split-values-into-separate-rows

Comment: Use a CLR string splitter.

Comment: Have a look here http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Redesign your database so that your data is atomic and doesn't require string-parsing functions.

Comment: @TabAlleman have you ever worked in on clients DB? Sometimes it's not an option you see...